# DAX Calculate Filter with Two Related Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, filtering

I am trying to make a DAX calculation that has a filter based on three related tables. My dataset is structured as shown below, with all tables having a one-to-many relationship with the Stops table.

I am trying to get a summarized average service time excluding any instance of when a customer did not have any volume on a specific day.

For example, if 7-Eleven had no sales volume on 9/1/2022, but had service time, I would not want to include that service time in the calculation.

I'm also converting the service time in seconds to decimal form by dividing by 3,600. My first attempt at a formula would look like this:

```html
CALCULATE(
    DIVIDE(AVERAGE([Service]), 3600), Stops[Volume]> 0)
```

But this is not giving me the proper number. Any assistance on how to calculate this using DAX?

[image]